# Show all .txt files from a folder in an activity

Tags: android, file-browser

I have a application where the user can write a text into a `EditText` and the written text is saved in an auto generated `.txt` file.

Now I want to show all the txt files from the folder in an activity, not like a regular file browser, just the title of the `.txt` files in a `ListView` or as a `TextView` (each file is illustrated as a TextView).

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: In this case nothing, I don't know how to realize it. I can show the recent added Text in a TextView in the next activity, but only one

Comment: so are you looking for whole source code?

Answer (score 1):

Get the path of that directory as string and create a new `file` with this path then,

```
String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"..../yourFolder"; 

File file=new File(path);
```

or

```
File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"..../yourFolder");
```

Use `file.list` which will give u all files name in form of an array then use a for loop with `endsWith` function and store data into a list like this

```
String arr[]=file.list();
List l=new ArrayList<>();
for(String i:arr){
    if(i.endsWith(".txt")){
       l.add(i);
    }
}
```

you will have names all text files under selected directory in list `l`

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 you can use [Files API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) and [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

```
Files
    .list(Paths.get("."))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```